# How to implement SCORM in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scorm

Do you know how to implement **SCORM (Sharable Content Object Reference Model)** in Objective C for eLearning content? Let me explain you what exactly I am looking for.

I have one MCQ (multiple choice question) application which has 4 questions. On attempting each question I want my application to interact with a SCORM compatible server with result (whether the user has attempted correct one or not). The communication channel should be to and fro. May be at the end of the MCQ I want to show result which will come from the server with some calculations**(like Score : 85% number of attempts : 16 average score:16.7% etc.)**.

How should I go about it? Please guide if you have already achieved it

regards
Ranjan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not quite that simple for two reasons.

1) SCORM requires a "player" to communicate with. You can't directly communicate with a server from your application via SCORM. The SCORM LMS needs to launch your application and provide the communication channel.

2) The communication channel defined by SCORM is via JavaScript. SCORM is designed to operate in the browser not necessarily in applications.

If you application will be played in the context of a SCORM player on the iPxx then the trick for you is enabling communication between Objective C and JavaScript. I don't know enough about Objective C to tell you how to do that, but if you can make it happen, the rest is just [straightforward SCORM](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/).

SCORM is currently 10 years old and is in the process of being modernized to support use cases like you describe. One of those modernization projects is being conducted by [LETSI](http://wiki.letsi.org/display/Arch/LETSI+RTWS+Developer's+Guide) and involves the creation of a web services based communication API for SCORM. It is in early release now, but it is has been prototyped for delivering iPhone content. Hopefully the industry will begin to support some of these more modern technologies soon.